# I am getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'query' in python

Tags: python, boto3

```
source_table = raw_input("Enter the table name : ")
PK = raw_input("Enter the primary key : ")
PriKeyData = raw_input("Enter the data type for Primary key int-number, str-string :" )
with open('PriSortKeys.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='|')
    for row in csvreader:
        if PriKeyData == "int":
                prikeyvalue = int(row[0])
            else:
                prikeyvalue = str(row[0])
            logger.info("Checking for Key :" + str(prikeyvalue))
            ## Fetching data from table based on primarykey
            sourcetable_data= source_table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key(PK).eq(prikeyvalue))
```

I am trying to take primary key and its value as user input and trying to query on that but i am getting the following error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'query'

Comment: `source_table = raw_input()`... That's always a `str`... What object are you trying to run `query()` against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
source_table = raw_input("Enter the table name : ")
```

will return just the name of the table, not the table itself. You have to open the table first and then `query()` on the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
source_table = raw_input("Enter the table name : ")
PK = raw_input("Enter the primary key : ")
PriKeyData = raw_input("Enter the data type for Primary key int-number, str-string :" )
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
s_table = dynamodb.Table(source_table.format(**locals()))
with open('PriSortKeys.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='|')
    for row in csvreader:
        if PriKeyData == "int":
                prikeyvalue = int(row[0])
            else:
                prikeyvalue = str(row[0])
        logger.info("Checking for Key :" + str(prikeyvalue))
        ## Fetching data from table based on primarykey
        s_table = source_table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key(PK).eq(prikeyvalue))
```